# R - Plot interpolated values a different colour in time series plot?

Tags: r, plot

Can someone help me. I have a dataset that had NA values that I have interpolated with zoo. I have added a 'colour column' in the hope that I could create a line plot (time series) with the interpolated values plotted in a different colour to the rest of the line. That is, the segment of the line defined by the point immediately before and immediately after the interpolated point should be red, and not black.

I've attached an example of my table here (where the colour is 'red' defines the values that have been interpolated). I've also put an image of the graph so far and the desired output here too:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_eJi0urUAzFM0JBS1ZIbUdGck0&usp=drive_web

This is my code thus far. The 'lines' part of the code is where I hoped to define the colour as the column in the data frame:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1), mar=c(4,4.5,2,2), mgp=c(2,0.6,0))
x.limit <- round(range(UN.GRACE.Int$DecimDate), 2)
plot(NULL, type="n", xlim=x.limit, ylim=c(-20, 25), xlab="Year", ylab="GRACE-TWS (cm)",     axes=F)
box(lwd=1.5)
abline(h=0, col="gray50", lty=1)
axis(1, seq(2003, 2012, 1), cex.axis=0.8)
axis(2, seq(-20, 25, 5), las=1, cex.axis=0.8)
minor.tick(nx=4, ny=0, tick.ratio=0.5) 
lines(UN.GRACE.Int[,2] ~ UN.GRACE.Int[,1], type="l", lwd=3, col=UN.GRACE.Int[,3])
tws.slope <- round(as.vector(coef(lm(UN.GRACE.Int[,2] ~ UN.GRACE.Int[,1]))[2]), 2)
tws.sdev <- round(as.vector(coef(summary(lm(UN.GRACE.Int[,2] ~ UN.GRACE.Int[,1])))[,  "Std. Error"][2]), 2)
abline(lm(UN.GRACE.Int[,2] ~ UN.GRACE.Int[,1]), lwd=2.5, lty=2, col=2)
mtext(paste("Trend (cm/year): ", tws.slope, "±", tws.sdev, sep=""), cex=0.8, side=1,  line=-1.1)
```

Any help would be appreciated - Thanks

Comment: So, you want to get a single line as output, not two lines, am I understanding you correctly? Could you share an image of what you're thinking (even a Paint drawing would be fine).

Comment: Yes that's what I need:) Here's a Picture:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_eJi0urUAzFV09tN0hLWHlnbnc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: How do you decide the length of the line segment to be colored? That's really the tricky thing, you can see my answers below but they both color the points. EDITED: In thinking about it further, the best way would be to overplot ANOTHER line on top of the first line if that's what you need, you'll need to feed the parameters to `line()` though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I realised the length of the segment might be tricky to plot. This appears the most sensible answer so thanks!

Comment: Is the length always the distance to the next point? If so, I can potentially edit in a solution...I think that's relatively doable.

Comment: As the values are interpolated with linear interpolation, the length of the segment will be the distance between the two neighbouring points - e.g. with the first value in the dataset (row 6) I'd be looking for a line from point 5 to 7 if this makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want the interpolated points to show up with a different color. You can accomplish this using the `type="o"` option in R, which gives over-plotted lines. Here's some adjusted code that produces the following plot. I took the minor.tick command out because it must have been from a package I don't have, but otherwise it works fine (using R 2.15.3 on my local machine).

You'll notice that I just plot the item directly, rather than calling plot to NULL and then adding in lines. This simplifies the code substantially. You can play with the `pch` parameter in the plot call to change the symbols used, and also alter the `lwd` parameters as needed. In fact, you could easily give a different value to `pch` for the interpolated values, like you did color - it accepts a vector as an argument.

```
par(mar=c(4,4.5,2,2), mgp=c(2,0.6,0))
x.limit <- round(range(UN.GRACE.Int$DecimDate), 2)
plot(UN.GRACE.Int[,2] ~ UN.GRACE.Int[,1],
     type="o",
     pch=18,
     col=UN.GRACE.Int[,3],
     xlim=x.limit,
     ylim=c(-20, 25),
     xlab="Year",
     ylab="GRACE-TWS (cm)",
     axes=F)
box(lwd=1.5)
abline(h=0, col="gray50", lty=1)
axis(1, seq(2003, 2012, 1), cex.axis=0.8)
axis(2, seq(-20, 25, 5), las=1, cex.axis=0.8)
tws.slope <- round(as.vector(coef(lm(UN.GRACE.Int[,2] ~ UN.GRACE.Int[,1]))[2]), 2)
tws.sdev <- round(as.vector(coef(summary(lm(UN.GRACE.Int[,2] ~ UN.GRACE.Int[,1])))[,  "Std. Error"][1]), 2)
abline(lm(UN.GRACE.Int[,2] ~ UN.GRACE.Int[,1]), lwd=2.5, lty=2, col=2)
mtext(paste("Trend (cm/year): ", tws.slope, "±", tws.sdev, sep=""), cex=0.8, side=1,  line=-1.1)
```

[image: Example of Plot using Overplot Instead of Line]

You could also add the points later if you JUST want to see the points where the data was interpolated. This could be done as follows:

```
par(mar=c(4,4.5,2,2), mgp=c(2,0.6,0))
x.limit <- round(range(UN.GRACE.Int$DecimDate), 2)
plot(UN.GRACE.Int[,2] ~ UN.GRACE.Int[,1],
     type="l",
     pch=18,
     col="black",
     xlim=x.limit,
     ylim=c(-20, 25),
     xlab="Year",
     ylab="GRACE-TWS (cm)",
     axes=F)
box(lwd=1.5)
abline(h=0, col="gray50", lty=1)
axis(1, seq(2003, 2012, 1), cex.axis=0.8)
axis(2, seq(-20, 25, 5), las=1, cex.axis=0.8)
tws.slope <- round(as.vector(coef(lm(UN.GRACE.Int[,2] ~ UN.GRACE.Int[,1]))[2]), 2)
tws.sdev <- round(as.vector(coef(summary(lm(UN.GRACE.Int[,2] ~ UN.GRACE.Int[,1])))[,  "Std. Error"][3]), 2)
abline(lm(UN.GRACE.Int[,2] ~ UN.GRACE.Int[,1]), lwd=2.5, lty=2, col=2)
mtext(paste("Trend (cm/year): ", tws.slope, "±", tws.sdev, sep=""), cex=0.8, side=1,  line=-1.1)
points(x=UN.GRACE.Int[UN.GRACE.Int$Col.CSR=="red",1],
       y=UN.GRACE.Int[UN.GRACE.Int$Col.CSR=="red",2],
       pch=16,
       col="red")
```

[image: Data with Only Interpolated Points Overplotted]

EDITED TO ADD: This is a way to color the line segments themselves by overplotting the original plot, assuming the distance to be colored is always of length one. It uses a quick'n'dirty `for()` loop, but it could be made into a function if you wanted.

```
par(mar=c(4,4.5,2,2), mgp=c(2,0.6,0))
x.limit <- round(range(UN.GRACE.Int$DecimDate), 2)
plot(UN.GRACE.Int[,2] ~ UN.GRACE.Int[,1],
     type="l",
     pch=18,
     col="black",
     xlim=x.limit,
     ylim=c(-20, 25),
     xlab="Year",
     ylab="GRACE-TWS (cm)",
     axes=F)
box(lwd=1.5)
abline(h=0, col="gray50", lty=1)
axis(1, seq(2003, 2012, 1), cex.axis=0.8)
axis(2, seq(-20, 25, 5), las=1, cex.axis=0.8)
tws.slope <- round(as.vector(coef(lm(UN.GRACE.Int[,2] ~ UN.GRACE.Int[,1]))[2]), 2)
tws.sdev <- round(as.vector(coef(summary(lm(UN.GRACE.Int[,2] ~ UN.GRACE.Int[,1])))[,  "Std. Error"][5]), 2)
abline(lm(UN.GRACE.Int[,2] ~ UN.GRACE.Int[,1]), lwd=2.5, lty=2, col=2)
mtext(paste("Trend (cm/year): ", tws.slope, "±", tws.sdev, sep=""), cex=0.8, side=1,  line=-1.1)

line_segs <- cbind(lstart=UN.GRACE.Int[which(UN.GRACE.Int$Col.CSR=="red")-1,c("DecimDate","CSR")],
                   lend=UN.GRACE.Int[which(UN.GRACE.Int$Col.CSR=="red")+1,c("DecimDate","CSR")])

for(x in 1:nrow(line_segs)) {

    lines(x=c(line_segs[x,1],line_segs[x,3]),
          y=c(line_segs[x,2],line_segs[x,4]),
          lwd=3,
          col="red")
}
```

[image: With Overplotting of Lines]